# How to assign text to the rich textbox control when mouse pointer pointing on the image using wpf?

Tags: wpf, image, controls, richtextbox

I have images. When the mouse pointer is pointing/over that image, the image description should be visible on rich text box? How?

Please, any one have idea? Please revert me ASAP

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `Trigger` to the image that sets the RichTextBox's content when the property (`IsMouseOver`) is set to `true`. Check out [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.trigger.aspx) for more information

Answer (score 0):

private void image1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = "angelfish1";
        }

```
    private void image2_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "clownfish";
    }

    private void image3_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "exotic";
    }

    private void image4_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "seahorse";
    }
```